# How to dynamically change true/false statement inside json object in React.js

Tags: json, reactjs, data-structures, react-component, react-state

I'm trying to add and remove product when clicking a button, and each button is in different component and the data that I'm getting from is in storeData component where inside there is an object with a true/false status if the status is true the product should display in Cart component if false it will remove the product.

now in ProductList component when I click the add button the status is changing to true, but it's not changing the actual status in storeData component so the result when i go to Cart component nothing is displayed

I know I'm doing this the wrong way, so how can I perform this add and remove operation, i'm new in React.js so please any help would really be appreciated.

ProductList component

```
import itemlist from "../storeData/storeData";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    items: itemlist.items,
    addToCart: null
  };
  addItem(id) {
    let itemArray = [];
    itemlist.cartItems.filter(target => {
      return id === target.id ? itemArray.push(target) : null;
    });
    const addToCart = itemArray[0];
    addToCart.status = false;
    this.setState({ addToCart });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-wrap">
        {this.state.items.map(item => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <Link to={{ pathname: "/productdetail", itemdetail: item }}>
                <img alt="item img" src={item.posterUrl} />
              </Link>
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              <h3>${item.price}</h3>
              <button onClick={() => this.addItem(item.id)}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

Cart component

```
import itemlist from "../storeData/storeData";

class Cart extends Component {
  state = {
    cart: itemlist.cartItems,
    remove: null
  };
  removeItem(id) {
    let itemArray = [];
    itemlist.cartItems.filter(target => {
      return id === target.id ? itemArray.push(target) : null;
    });
    let remove = itemArray[0];
    remove.status = false;
    this.setState({ remove });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.cart.map(itm => {
          return itm.status === false ? null : (
            <div key={itm.id} className="cart-layout">
              <img alt="img" src={itm.posterUrl} />
              <h4>{itm.title}</h4>
              <h4>{itm.price}</h4>
              <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(itm.id)}>Remove</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

storeData component

```
let itemlist = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "name 1",
      price: "232",
      posterUrl:
        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "name 2",
      price: "65",
      posterUrl:
        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5NTc2NjYwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzk5OTY0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
  ],
  cartItems: [
    {
      id: 1,
      status: false,
      title: "name 1",
      price: "232",
      posterUrl:
        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      status: false,
      title: "name 2",
      price: "65",
      posterUrl:
        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5NTc2NjYwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzk5OTY0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using filter correctly here, in either component. You are confusing the filter test with the action of composing your array. All you need with the filter is a test that will return a boolean and that will construct the array for you.

Try changing:

```
let itemArray = [];
itemlist.cartItems.filter(target => {
      return id === target.id ? itemArray.push(target) : null;
    });
```

To

```
const itemArray = itemlist.cartItems.filter(target => id === target.id);
```

And similarly in the cart component.

For more detail on `filter` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter